# interpolation across multiple columns with numeric and string columns

Tags: python, pandas

I have a data frame that looks like:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

d={'business':['FX','FX','FX','IR','IR','IR'],\
'A/L':['A','A','A','A','A','A'],\
'date':(['01/01/2018','02/01/2018','03/01/2018','04/01/2018',\
'05/01/2018','06/01/2018']),\
'amt':[np.nan,2,3,np.nan,5,6]}
df=pd.DataFrame(data=d)
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'],format='%d/%m/%Y')
df=df.interpolate()
df
```

Using the above code, I get a NaN in the first row as expected. However, I want interpolate to take the other columns into consideration as well, ie I would expect to see a NaN instead of 4.
[image]

Any ideas how to hand situations like this with multiple columns of text/dates and not just two ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may need `groupby`

```
df.groupby('business').apply(pd.Series.interpolate)
Out[55]: 
  A/L  amt business       date
0   A  NaN       FX 2018-01-01
1   A  2.0       FX 2018-01-02
2   A  3.0       FX 2018-01-03
3   A  NaN       IR 2018-01-04
4   A  5.0       IR 2018-01-05
5   A  6.0       IR 2018-01-06
```